# comparing fields and relationship fields via before and after update

Tags: trigger, callout, triggercontext

I am making a callout on Insert, Update or Delete of a record. This question pertains to the update of the record, in order to make the process more efficient from Salesforce below is what I am trying to achieve:

1. Make a callout only if certain fields on the object or the lookup objects are updated. What's the best way possible to implement this?

Since, relationship fields are not accessible in `trigger.new` or `trigger.old` and below mentioned are 2 separate instances, how can I call a single method to compare certain values?

```
    trigger.isUpdate(){
           trigger.isBefore(){
           }

           trigger.isAfter(){
           }

    }
```

**Ideally, what I would like to do is** (*Pseudo Code*):

```
     Before Update
       - Query the values using trigger.old ( Select fields, relationship fields from Object where id in: Trigger.old)
       - store these values in a map

     After Update
       - Query the values using trigger.new (Select fields, relationship fields from Object where id in: trigger.new)
       - store these values in a map

Call a method to compare these maps.
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before Update and After Update are 2 different transactions in APEX. So, comparing the data will be impossible. Storing the info in a custom setting or a custom object in the before update call and fetch them in a after update call.

You will then be able to compare the values.

Answer (score 1):

You can get relationship fields in a trigger by using the `trigger.new` or `trigger.old` maps by using `trigger.newMap.keySet()` or `trigger.oldMap.keySet()` which return the ID's of the records in the trigger. Example code:

```
if (trigger.isBefore)
{
    Map <String, String> contactMap = new Map <String, String> ();

    for (Contact contact : [SELECT Name, Account.Name FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :trigger.newMap.keySet()])
    {
        contactMap.put(contact.Name, contact.Account.Name);
    }
}

if (trigger.isAfter)
{
    Map <String, String> anotherSObjectMap = new Map <String, String> ();

    for (AnothersObject sObject2 : [SELECT Name, Parent__r.CustomField__c FROM AnothersObject WHERE Id IN :trigger.oldMap.keySet()])
    {
        anotherSObjectMap.put(sObject2.Name, sObject2.Parent__r.CustomField__c);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to store and compare but this is how you can get the values. You might only need a Set instead of map. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am aware that this is possible, but what I am trying to achieve is comparing the values before and after update. i.e. for example if the Contact name and Account.Name are 2 fields that changed, I would want to know that account.name changed as well from the trigger on Contact. Does that make sense? So, I was trying to write an apex method to compare the fields from Before update and After update.

Comment: The before and after triggers I believe are 2 separate transactions in APEX and you have new instances in each. You will need to store the data (maybe in an sObject or a field) in the before trigger and compare it with the after.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: 1 up for the prompt help Bachovski! :)

Answer (score 1):

I take this to be the heart of he question:

> Make a callout only if certain fields on the object or the lookup
>   objects are updated

If by "lookup objects" you mean that you want to make a callout when fields of a related object are updated, then you will need to **add triggers to those objects too** to detect changes.

It is not necessary to try to store values across triggers and it would be hard to get such code right given that the triggers can fire multiple times - see e.g. [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm). The information you need to detect changes is supplied by the framework in the form of `Trigger.oldMap`/`Trigger.old` and `Trigger.newMap`/`Trigger.new`.

If you are trying to just make one callout when fields on two different objects change (as your comment mentions) I suggest that that is hard to accomplish in Force.com and you would need a strong reason to do it for the complicated code and unit tests to be justified.

(Normal Force.com UI only updates fields in one object. If you have some logic that updates multiple objects then perhaps you should make the callout in that logic.)